# SpringBootTest cant fill Map in my Service

Tags: java, spring, testing

i have this service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RepoService{
    private final Map<EnumRepoType, EnumRepo<? extends AbstractType>> firstMap;
    private final Map<RepoType, Repo<? extends AbstractType>> secondMap;

    public DictionaryService(List<EnumRepo<? extends AbstractType>> enumTypeRepositories,
                             List<Repo<? extends AbstractType>> typeRepositories) {
        this.firstMap= enumTypeRepositories.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(EnumRepo::getType, i -> i));
        this.secondMap= typeRepositories.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Repo::getType, i -> i));
    }
}
```

EnumRepoType and RepoType is enum.
When my app is starting, this map fill automatically with springbooot. But! when i write test for my app,  this map cant fill automatically!

I write stupid simple test for this question ->

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RepoService.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "package.with.repo.class"
})
public class RepoServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    RepoService repoService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("whyyy map in repoService empty???");
    }
}
```

I do not understand(((

with @DataJpaTest map is filled in correctly! with an empty @SpringBootTest() too, but the app starts too long(the whole context starts), i dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RepoService.class})
```

This is specifying the configurations used for the test. That means RepoService is the *only* bean in this test context, so it makes sense that the maps are empty, because they are looking for other beans.

If you add beans which implement EnumRepo you will fill the map:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RepoService.class, ENTER_HERE_REPO_NAME.class})
```

The reason why @DataJpaTest or @SpringBootTest() works, is because they load more beans into the spring context.

Comment: but I have ~50 repository classes and add them all manually...

Comment: no you have not, since the maps are empty. You can set a breakpoint there and it will show you that the lists are empty. Your ComponentScan is likely not working as you expect. In which packages are the tests? In which packages are the repos? Is ComponentScan even working on test classes? Can you create @TestConfiguration class which contains the ComponentScan annotation etc?